# Intellij Idea 14.0.3 build 139.117 (can't rebuild project)

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I know this is already been asked here
[IntelliJ IDEA - Can't build anything, always get "package R does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686289/intellij-idea-cant-build-anything-always-get-package-r-does-not-exist)

but it does not solved my problem.I always get package R does not exists every time I rebuild the project.

I hope someone can guide me how to fixed this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `./gradlew clean` or `ant clean` from your module's folder in terminal/cmd.  Then hit run (Shift F10) or debug (Shift F9) until jetbrains releases 14.0.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with 14.0.3. Reverting back to 14.0.2 worked for me. It looks like it works for others too according to a [JetBrain forum post](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/460176;jsessionid=EA4796D04664CA594052EF5B0F90E5EC?tstart=0).

Comment: 14.1 came out today (2015-03-24)...looks like they fixed it

Comment: Update that breaks things. Crappy