# Intellij IDEA 14 - Running unupdated app

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA for several month already and today I faced the problem: IDEA was running the previous version of my project.

I've made some changes (added TextView) in my layout file and checked everything. Then I've run the project on emulator (Genymotion) and it was screen without TextView. I've checked every line one more time to make sure the error was not there. Then I've connected my phone throw USB and run the project on the phone: the same. Then I've generatend APK file and placed it to the phone. !!After running the TextView was there!!.

I've decided to rebuild the project and IDEA said: *Compilation completed with 0 errors and 0 warnings in 0 sec*

So the questions: What is the reason? & How to make everything work?

**P.S** Reinstalling and cleaning cashes do not help. IntelliJ IDEA version: 14.0.3

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28251004/intellij-idea-14-0-3-build-139-117-cant-rebuild-project    (go back to 14.0.2)

Answer (score 0):

As @petey said I've changed the version but everything were the same. Then reload my computer and updated IDEA to 14.0.3. Now everything works perfectly. I think it was just a bug