# Android Studio main activity file is misbehaving

Tags: android

I am newbie in android development and i'm facing these following errors in my first program :
i am using android studio 1.5.1
1) Package R does not exist 
2) package name com.example.android.justjava; does not corresponding to the file path package com.example.machine.justjava; Please help me out . I am putting the screenshot as well
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oXgQ.jpg)

Comment: Import com.example.machine.justjava.R in your activity.

Comment: try to extend AppCompatActivity and not ActionBarActivity you are extending now.

Comment: ActionBarActivity is deprecated but has nothing to do with the problem he is facing!

Comment: View this question. It would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686289/intellij-idea-cant-build-anything-always-get-package-r-does-not-exist

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

1. Clean your project. That does it sometimes.
2. If still not resolved then you will have to import the R class. Go to app\build\generated\source\r\debug\android\support\v7\appcompat\R. See the package and import it in your activity. By the error message I think you should just import com.example.machine.justjava.R;